# How can I re-import DeliveryAPI result in kentico kontent

Tags: json, kentico-kontent

I want to try [kontent-sample-blog-travel-vue](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-sample-blog-travel-vue) project in github, and it has JSON contents under 'sample-data' directory in Delivery API format.
I made my new Kontent project, and try to use ManagementAPI to import json, but it becomes error because of wrong JSON format.
Please tell me how can I re-import JSON, which exported in Delivery API format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right, to import data from Delivery API to Management API, you need to make the transformations.

I have started with [the pull request](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-sample-blog-travel-vue/pull/19), which should guide people on [how to import data using backup manager CLI, or via template manager UI](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-sample-blog-travel-vue/tree/fix/8#create-content-source).

Once the pull request is merged, I will update this answer.

---

**EDIT:**

OK, the pull request is closed and now the **Vue travel blog sample site is ready to be used as a template**.

In the readme, you can find [instructions on how to create your own Kontent project as data source](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-sample-blog-travel-vue#create-your-kontent-project-as-data-source).

If you have any more questions/issues, feel free to submit an issue (or pull request) right in the repository.

> This repository was also submitted as one of the templates in the [Kontent template manager](https://kentico.github.io/kontent-template-manager/templates).

---

Comment: Response adjusted :)